Video Won't Play In Safari
I have a video that I'd like to place on my website.
<video controls playsinline>
<source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

I have no trouble getting the video to play on any browser other than Safari. However, on Safari, only the video controls display, and I'm unable to play the video.
I tried adding the muted tag and saving my video as an H.264-encoded video via QuickTime Player, but this didn't help either. This is not a background video.
I have looked at other forums such as [HTML5 Video tag not working in Safari, iPhone and iPad], but I still can't get the video to play.
Does Safari not support HTML5 video? Is there any workaround?
Any advice would be much appreciated.

I’ve not had any trouble getting Safari to play HTML 5 video. Have you had a look at the console in web inspector to see if there are any errors reported? Can you host your video on the web somewhere and then build a stack snippet to play it? Edit your post, copying the snippet from my answer below, replacing the link with a link to your video.

@Richard Make sure both myvideo.mp4 and your page have an online path starting with https://. Add a width and height to the <video> tag. Test again in Safari... Also, is it possible that your MP4 may be a different file type (like MKV) just renamed into being .mp4? Check the file at MediaInfo website and tell us the (General) Format and Codec ID, then also under (Video) tell us the Format, Format profile, Chroma subsampling, Scan type.. Sorry its long for you but this is yet another website video issue with no testable website link

Sounds like there is an issue which is specific to your video ... in which case we'll need you to post a link to your video.

Safari definitely supports HTML 5 video.


video {
  width: 300px;
}
<video controls>
  <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>




Safari does in fact support HTML5 video playback.

saving my video as an H.264-encoded video via QuickTime Player

Verify that myvideo.mp4 is encoded with H.264 for video and AAC for audio. You can use ffmpeg to inspect and re-encode the file:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.mp4
On the other hand, I suggest you check the Console tab in the Safari's web insspector to see if any form of error/warning(s) are logged.
Keep in mind that having fallback code can be helpful to debug the issue for example:
<video controls playsinline>
    <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    This browser does not support the video.
</video>

A final (unrelated?) note, if you're using React or NextJs you should use the camel cased playsInline instead. otherwise it won't work

I've checked the video file I'm using and it is encoded with H.264 for video and AAC for audio. Is there any other method I could try?
